# SQL Server - Performance variance querying an empty table

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, glassfish

Background:
We have a `SQL  Server`   backend, and a Java application, running on `glassfish`.
Within glassfish, they use the connection pool validation function.

Originally, they pointed the connection pool validator at the sys.tables catalogue, but we noticed performance problems. We resolved it by creating an  `'empty'`   table; `dbo.ConnectionValidation (Valid BIT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY)`. Horray, problems mostly solved.

Lately, our jva guys (using `AppDynamics`) have caught exceptional cases where it takes up to 13seconds to query this empty table.

The Problem:
In an effort to prove that the DB was not the issue, I set up a script to query the table over and over, and record the time. 99% of the calls are 0ms or immeasurable, however every so often (once every few hundred thousand times), it spikes to `500-1500ms`. To me that is an eternity, to do nothing!

I refined the query further and ACTUALLY did nothing, i recorded a  `timestamp` , and then immediately recorded another and I still saw the spikes. Maybe the issue is in the time function?

The Query:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE
    @TimestampUTC   DATETIME,
    @TimestampUTC2  DATETIME,
    @Duration       INT,
    @Counter        BIGINT = 1,
    @DummyValue     BIT

WHILE @Counter < 1000000000 --1 billion
BEGIN
    SET @TimestampUTC = SYSUTCDATETIME()
    SET @TimestampUTC2 = SYSUTCDATETIME()

    --SELECT @DummyValue = Valid
    --FROM dbo.ConnectionValidator

    SET @Duration = DATEDIFF(ms, @TimeStampUTC, @TimestampUTC2)

    IF  @Duration > 10
        PRINT CAST(@Duration AS VARCHAR) + 'ms. Execution#: ' + cast(@Counter AS VARCHAR)

    SET @Counter += 1
END
```

Run this on your system, and see what happens?
How can it suddenly someties take so long! What is happening here?
Could this explain the random spikes that the java app experiences?

Comment: Here's something similar. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/123370/application-querying-empty-tables

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your DB is having an IO problem with the underlying data files.

Try running some of the queries listed by [this MSDN blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/askjay/archive/2011/07/08/troubleshooting-slow-disk-i-o-in-sql-server.aspx?Redirected=true) to see if you're waiting on disk IO.

Comment: I thought that originally, but how would IO be involved? Everything is in memory in that example. Nothing is read from, or written to the disk.